# Alert & Prompt in Firebase Functions (index.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to make a simple website with Firebase Functions.

1. I have to display a prompt to ask their import id.
2. I will then set the answer as a variable.
3. Then import their data with the import code

Following is that code in `index.js`

```
async function getFirestore() {
    var importcode = prompt("What is the Import Code?");
    const firestore_con = await admin.firestore();
    const writeResult = firestore_con
        .collection("Exports")
        .doc(importcode)
        .get()
        .then((doc) => {
            if (!doc.exists) {
                console.log("No such document!");
            } else {
                return doc.data();
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Error getting document", err);
        });
    return writeResult;
}
```

and I get this in the Debug Log.

```
i  functions: Beginning execution of "us-central1-app"
>  /Users/randomkindleofficial/Desktop/monopoly-dynamic/functions/index.js:19
>      var importcode = prompt("What is the Import Code?");
>                       ^
>  
>  ReferenceError: prompt is not defined
>      at getFirestore (/Users/randomkindleofficial/Desktop/monopoly-dynamic/functions/index.js:19:22)
>      at /Users/randomkindleofficial/Desktop/monopoly-dynamic/functions/index.js:39:27
>      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/randomkindleofficial/Desktop/monopoly-dynamic/functions/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>      at next (/Users/randomkindleofficial/Desktop/monopoly-dynamic/functions/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
>      at Route.dispatch (/Users/randomkindleofficial/Desktop/monopoly-dynamic/functions/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
>      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/randomkindleofficial/Desktop/monopoly-dynamic/functions/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>      at /Users/randomkindleofficial/Desktop/monopoly-dynamic/functions/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
>      at Function.process_params (/Users/randomkindleofficial/Desktop/monopoly-dynamic/functions/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
>      at next (/Users/randomkindleofficial/Desktop/monopoly-dynamic/functions/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
>      at expressInit (/Users/randomkindleofficial/Desktop/monopoly-dynamic/functions/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
>      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/randomkindleofficial/Desktop/monopoly-dynamic/functions/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>      at trim_prefix (/Users/randomkindleofficial/Desktop/monopoly-dynamic/functions/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
>      at /Users/randomkindleofficial/Desktop/monopoly-dynamic/functions/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
>      at Function.process_params (/Users/randomkindleofficial/Desktop/monopoly-dynamic/functions/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
>      at next (/Users/randomkindleofficial/Desktop/monopoly-dynamic/functions/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
>      at query (/Users/randomkindleofficial/Desktop/monopoly-dynamic/functions/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/query.js:45:5)
```

I think this happens because `index.js` runs on the server-side, **but are there any alternatives to achieve this?**

*PS: I only have very basic knowledge in firebase, so this may be a foolish question but still please help :)*

Answer (score 0):

The [`prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) method can be used in a browser and not on server side i.e. in the Cloud function. I am not sure what your frontend looks like, but you should prompt the user to enter ID in your web app and then pass it in the Cloud function. A simple example using callable functions:

```
var importcode = prompt("What is the Import Code?");

var getData = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('getData');
getData({ code: importCode })
  .then((result) => {
    // Read result of the Cloud Function.
    var result = result.data;
    console.log(result)
  });
```

Then you can read this code in your Cloud function like this:

```
exports.getData = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  console.log(data)
  // data contains the import code
  // run your Firestore query here
});
```

Comment: Can you tell more about the callable function?

Comment: @RandomKindle can you share more details about your frontend code first? Where is the `getFirestore` being called?